# Windows setup doesn't detect HDD, although it is detected in BIOS

Tags: windows, hard-drive, bios, setup

I've been trying to reconfigure and reinstall an old machine that I've been using until recently to pass it down to relatives, but I have no success installing Windows in the current configuration.

- Motherboard: Intel DG965RY
- Disk drive: Samsung HD753LJ (that's the only change in configuration - I've been using a SSD drive before)

When I check the drives in BIOS it correctly reports the attached model and it's size. When I run the Windows setup, there's no drives available. I've tried adding the [official storage drivers](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=10884&lang=eng&ProdId=2377) at this point, without success.

I updated the BIOS to the [latest version](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=17520&lang=eng&ProdId=2377), nothing changed.

I've experimented with BIOS settings for the SATA controller (Native/Legacy, IDE/AHCI), still the same.

I tried different version of Windows (made no difference):

- Windows Vista (tha machine came with it)
- Windows 7 SP1 (from my MSDN subscription)
- Windows 8.1 Update (from my MSDN subscription)

I checked the disk with Samsung's diagnostic tool [ES Tool](http://web.archive.org/web/20110617014546/http://www.samsung.com/global/business/hdd/support/downloads/support_in_es.html) from [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/). It detected no errors.

What am I missing? What else can I try?

Comment: does the drive show up on any other machine? If so, & you are using legacy BIOS, just format it MBR/NTFS, try again.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for the suggestion. I didn't mention it, but the disk did show up on the new machine all the time. Now I've reinitialized it there as you suggested, and the disk showed up in setup on the old machine as well. Write an answer about it and I'll accept it.

Comment: I'm not sure it would convert to a full answer really. I'm glad you got it going, is all. I'll survive without the points;)